# Pass DataFrame variable name as string

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function to plot a graph:

```
def plot_ATD(DataFrame):
    #Initialise 225V ATD plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    #take columns from data set and make to list which is passed to matplotlib to plot a graph
    x = DataFrame['Arrival Time (ms)'].tolist()
    y = DataFrame['Intensity'].tolist()
    line, = ax.plot(x,y, 'r-')
    #use numpy to get the max of Intensity, then determine the corresponding arrival time
    ymax = np.max(y)
    xpos = y.index(ymax)
    xmax = x[xpos]
    time = xmax
    #add an annotation point at the maxima giving the arrival time at this position
    # ax.annotate(s=text of annotation, xy=point to annotate, xytext=position to place text
    #              arrowprops=dict(facecolor=color of arrow))
    ax.annotate(s=xmax, xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(xmax+5, ymax+5),
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='orange'),
               )
    #ax.set_ylim(0,600000)
    ax.set_xlim(0,20)
    plt.xlabel('Arrival time (ms)')
    plt.title(DataFrame.name)
    return plt.show()
```

I am using it on the following pandas DataFrames:

```
V100 = pd.read_csv('Documents/spreadsheets/Data/100V_9z.csv', names=['Arrival Time (ms)', 'Intensity'])
V125 = pd.read_csv('Documents/spreadsheets/Data/125V_9z.csv', names=['Arrival Time (ms)', 'Intensity'])
V150 = pd.read_csv('Documents/spreadsheets/Data/150V_9z.csv', names=['Arrival Time (ms)', 'Intensity'])
V175 = pd.read_csv('Documents/spreadsheets/Data/175V_9z.csv', names=['Arrival Time (ms)', 'Intensity'])
V200 = pd.read_csv('Documents/spreadsheets/Data/200V_9z.csv', names=['Arrival Time (ms)', 'Intensity'])
V225 = pd.read_csv('Documents/spreadsheets/Data/225V_9z.csv', names=['Arrival Time (ms)', 'Intensity'])
```

I want to have the title of the graph to be the name of the DataFrame i.e. V100, V125 etc.

I am not sure on the right syntax or how to do this? Please help!

Comment: So `plt.title(DataFrame.name)` does not work?

Comment: @b-fg - What is `DataFrame` here

Comment: It's OPs variable name for the dataframe in the function. I have commented on this bad practice in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a workaround:

```
Vs= [v for v in locals() if v.startswith('V')] 
for v in Vs:
    plot(eval(v),title=v)
```

A cleaner method (since `eval` is not secure) must be done when creating variables, for example with series (or dictionaries) :

```
ser=pd.Series()
ser['V100'] = pd.read_csv('Documents/spreadsheets/Data/100V_9z.csv', \
names=['Arrival Time (ms)', 'Intensity'])
```

will simplify the job.

Answer (score 4):

First, is not good practice to use `DataFrame` as the name of your dataframe in the function since it is the name of the `pandas.DataFrame` class itself. Better change it to `df` for example.

So you can set the name of the dataframe with (for example)

```
V100.name = 'V100'
```

And do this for all your dataframes. Then in your function call (the newly named) `df.name` to get the name you previously assigned to the dataframe.

**Update**

To automatically set the dataframe names you can simply do

```
file_name = 'Documents/spreadsheets/Data/100V_9z.csv'
V100 = pd.read_csv(file_name, names=['Arrival Time (ms)', 'Intensity'])
V100.name = file_name.split('/')[-1].split('_')[0] # 'V100'
```

Comment: May I know what is advantage over assigning this value in to another value and access it again instead of `df.name`?

Comment: Is a way to pass it to the function tied with the dataframe itself. No need to create other variables when there is a specific class attribute for this.

Comment: Happy to contribute :)

Comment: thank you this seems to work, So I have created the variables V100.name = 'V100' etc for each one outside the function. Is there no way to have the function do it within, so I could rename my dataframes and not have to redo the df.name variables?

Comment: This is not the original question... You can, I will update my question now.